# OR-Tools: Is there any way to get raw combinations and permutations?

Tags: or-tools

For example, you call something like permutations([1,2,3,4],2) or combinations([1,2,3,4],2) and get list of permutations/combinations like [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), ...]. Is it possible using exactly OR-Tools?

Comment: Yes. But the c++ stdlib does it for you.

Comment: Or c#. This was my answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/66125489/7424038. It would have to be slightly modified for your use, or you just pass a List containing two instances of your list [1,2,3,4], although it would then consider (1, 2) and (2, 1) to be separate permutations and would also return (1, 1) etc.