# All letter-combinations (n-items) according pattern

Tags: c#, linq, pattern-matching, combinations, populate

Im trying to decrypt a word which letters have been replaced with random other letters (but not 2 different letters into the same one).

**The goal:**
Im searching for a word which lenght and letter-pattern is known.

**What I know:**
The pattern itself means if searching for "guests" I know "123454" which shows the position of unique letters in this word. And for sure I know its an english word correctly written.

**Software side:**
I've created a `DataGridView` which headers are titled by the pattern. I want to populate each `Column` (pattern) with its possible combinations of all letters `a-z`.

**What I've tried:**
Ill start at the end => I've successfully implemented a spell-checker. So in the end I thought about just going through the columns and check for each result to find the actual word.

From the starting point seen I've written this so far:

```
private string[] alpha = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", ..."z"};
private int[] digits = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,....9 };

private void bruteforce()
{
    // Each Column
    foreach(DataGridViewColumn col in dgvResults.Columns)
    {
        // HeaderText to CharArray to IntArray (-48 to switch from ASCII to INT).
        int[] pattern = Array.ConvertAll(col.HeaderText.ToCharArray(), c => c - 48);

        // Prepare an result-array with the same length as the pattern.
        string[] resultSet = Enumerable.Repeat("-", pattern.Length).ToArray();

        // For each digit 0-9.
        foreach(int digit in digits)
        {
            // In pattern search for each digit and save the index.
            int[] indexes = pattern.FindAllIndexof(digit);
            // If index is found.
            if(indexes.Length > 0)
            {
                // Custom function ReplaceAtIndex. 
                // Replace resultSet-Values at given Indexes with unique letter
                resultSet.ReplaceAtIndex(indexes, alpha[digit]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Current result:**
A pattern of **`0112344`** will be saved (`resultSet`) as **`abbcdee`**.
Now I would need to loop the letters while staying on the same pattern.

This step feels even more complicated then the stuff before. I thought, before continuing blowing away my head, Im going to see if there are some genius guys out there on stackoverflow who can provide a shorter easier way (maybe some shortcuts with LINQ).

So please, is there anyone thinking "easy doin" about this who could help me?
I appreciate every help in here. Thanks

Comment: Eric Lippert has set of blog posts about [Producing combinations](http://ericlippert.com/2014/10/13/producing-combinations-part-one/) that can help you get all the combinations of n letters and then you could use his [Producing permutations](http://ericlippert.com/2013/04/15/producing-permutations-part-one/) posts to get all the ways to order the n letters and the apply them to your pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is IMO a quite effective algorithm for generating what are you asking for.

It's a variation of the algorithm I've used in [Looking at each combination in jagged array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35493785/looking-at-each-combination-in-jagged-array/35494340#35494340) and [System.OutOfMemoryException when generating permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35385506/system-outofmemoryexception-when-generating-permutations/35527854#35527854) and is optimized to perform minimum allocations.

```
public static class Algorithms
{
    private static readonly char[] alpha = Enumerable.Range('a', 'z' - 'a' + 1).Select(c => (char)c).ToArray();

    public static IEnumerable<string> GenerateWords(this string pattern)
    {
        return pattern.GenerateWordsCore().Select(word => new string(word));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<char[]> GenerateWordsCore(this string pattern)
    {
        var distinctSet = pattern.Select(c => c - '0').Distinct().ToArray();
        var indexMap = pattern.Select(c => Array.IndexOf(distinctSet, c - '0')).ToArray();
        var result = new char[pattern.Length];
        var indices = new int[distinctSet.Length];
        var indexUsed = new bool[alpha.Length];
        for (int pos = 0, index = 0; ;)
        {
            // Generate the next permutation
            if (index < alpha.Length)
            {
                if (indexUsed[index]) { index++; continue; }
                indices[pos] = index;
                indexUsed[index] = true;
                if (++pos < distinctSet.Length) { index = 0; continue; }
                // Populate and yield the result
                for (int i = 0; i < indexMap.Length; i++)
                    result[i] = alpha[indices[indexMap[i]]];
                yield return result;
            }
            // Advance to next permutation if any
            if (pos == 0) yield break;
            index = indices[--pos];
            indexUsed[index] = false;
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
bool test = "12334".GenerateWords().Contains("hello");
foreach (var word in "123454".GenerateWords())
{
    // Do something with word
}
```

Comment: Alright. So far, so nice. A test over "12345678" returns in no result. It for sure lists a los of combinations. But is it possible there are some left? And if so, why? Result-Count is 1562275. I checked the spelling with `NHuspell` (english-us). I know this pattern says that there are 8 different letters in this word.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, there is a problem, my algorithm is generating combinations, but what you really need is unique permutations. Don't worry, I'll adjust it and will post the update.

Comment: `foreach(string word in "1234".GenerateWords()) => if word.Contains("th")` isnt returning even 1 hit. What about "this" or "that" or "then" or "them"?

Comment: Oh alright. Thanks very much :). Btw.. respect for being able writing down such code in such short time.

Comment: @C4ud3x Took a bit more time than expected, but now should work (I hope:)

Comment: No problem. I'll verify this in the next hour. Thanks!

Comment: Now the real high count of combinations is incoming. Thanks for your effort :). Works now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105918/discussion-between-c4ud3x-and-ivan-stoev).